# GData Example for Iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, youtube, gdata

I need gdata api to play youtubevideo and save that video. Does anyone have any sample link or tutorial link?

Answer (score 2):

I used GData Api to fetch contacts from GMail. It was very simple but I don't know about Youtube stuff.

I used this [link](http://johntwang.com/blog/2009/06/08/how-to-use-google-apis-with-iphone-sdk/) to convert the GData API from Mac to iPhone support..

Now use the separate Youtube Example and copy/modify/edit the code according to your need.

Comment: @iPrabhu while implementing gData i m facing so many errors like redefinition of duplicate files. i checked many times but problem exists